# After disabling and uninstalling memcached module, I get this PDOException and WSOD?

Tags: caching, installation

I´ve cloned my production site in a local Xampp installation.
My site has Memcached installed (in the server and I´ve got the drupal memcache module installed).

But I´ve got this error at my local site:

> You must enable the PECL memcached or memcache extension to use
>   memcache.inc

(this is repeated at least 30 times, so that line is printed about 30 times at the top of every page).

Now, I´ve disable and unninstalled memcache at my local installation, and the error is still there.

I´ve tried after that deleting the additional settings added to my settings config file:

> $conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
>   $conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
>   $conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'memcache_sitio';
>   $conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';

But if I do eliminate those lines (after I´ve uninstalled -not only disabled- memcached module), I get WSOD and this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in
>   C:\Users\Vic\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\includes\database\database.inc:2139
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Users\Vic\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\includes\database\database.inc(2139):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   C:\Users\Vic\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\includes\database\database.inc(664):
>   DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array) #2
>   C:\Users\Vic\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\includes\database\database.inc(2318):
>   DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array) #3
>   C:\Users\Vic\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\includes\lock.inc(167):
>   db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array) #4
>   C:\Users\Vic\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\includes\lock.inc(146):
>   lock_may_be_available('schema:runtime:...') #5
>   C:\Users\Vic\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\includes\bootstrap.inc(405):
>   lock_acquire('schema:runtime:...') #6 C:\Users\Victoria in
>   C:\Users\Vic\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\drupal\includes\database\database.inc
>   on line 2139

Please note that I´ve deleted all cache, tried disabling (and enabling) all performance options, and I´ve run run cron more than once.

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Each time I saw the "Mysql server has gone away" error, it was caused by the max_allowed_packet setting (in the my.ini setting file) that was too small.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!! It´s here:
http://stannesi.blogspot.com.ar/2011/11/how-to-install-memcache-on-xampp.html

In a nutshell:
My Xampp php didn´t have any memcache extension, so, I have to add it:

After all the extensions declared in my php.ini file, I´ve added this:

```
extension=php_memcache.dll
[Memcache]
memcache.allow_failover = 1  
memcache.max_failover_attempts=20  
memcache.chunk_size =8192  
memcache.default_port = 11211
```

After that I have to download the php_memcache extension ([php_memcache.dll](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.6/php_memcache-3.0.6-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip)) and put it inside php/ext folder, in my Xampp installation.

And that was it!!

Hope this helps out someone, somewhere :)